# How can I type this format of equation in latex?

Tags: equations, brackets

[image: I specifically want braces on right side of the set of equations in given format.]
I specifically want braces on right side of the set of equations in given format.

Comment: You want us to type all that by ourself? Come on, you gotta be kidding ;-)

Comment: @ChrisS Probably it isn't a duplicate, since in the image I seem to see subequations inside an equation. See the equation numbers.

Comment: @ Harish Kumar , it is not the equation that I want you to type. I need the braces in the given format around the sub-equation. could you do that for me??

Comment: @Agog You've already asked other questions and didn't accepted one. Could you please start accepting answers (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)) and then ask for favours?

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something to start with.  The basic building blocks are

```
\left.
\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}
\right\}
```

which places a large brace to the right and no delimiter before.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcounter{mysubequations}

\renewcommand{\themysubequations}{(\roman{mysubequations})}

\newcommand{\mysubnumber}{\refstepcounter{mysubequations}\themysubequations}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \left.
    \begin{aligned}\setcounter{mysubequations}{0}
      &\!\max \nu = \text{whatever}&&\mysubnumber\\
      &\text{Subject to}&&\\
      &w + u = z \qquad\qquad \text{(normality condition)}&&\mysubnumber\\
      &\mkern-8mu\left.
        \begin{aligned}
          &w - u = 0\\
          &2w + 3u = 10
      \end{aligned}
      \right\} \qquad \text{(orthogonality condition)}&&\mysubnumber
    \end{aligned}
    \right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I have set up a counter to number the subconstructions, but the way `amsmath` handles labels means that you can't refer to these numbers via the usual `\label...\ref` mechanism, yet...I'll think more about this.

Note that nearly all the constructs in the example are adding various small spaces at the beginning of the lines hence the added negative kerns.

Comment: Thanks, but please don't support questions without MWEs.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Generally I agree MWEs are an extremely good thing.  However in this case, I felt there was a clear enough question to address and it is not clear to me that an MWE would get us much further.